# Rails - Updating a display of a database and displaying database elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model

I am trying to figure out how I would go about setting a view page to refresh its display of a table every 1 second or so without refreshing the page.

For my controller I have:

```
class SendMessageController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @list = model_table.last(10)
    end
```

For my view page I have:

```
<p><%= @list.each do |m| %>
<%= m.column1 %><br>
<% end %><p>
```

I would like it to refresh @list every 1 second so I have an up to date list
Also after it outputs the last 10 items in column1, why does it output everything in the database?

Comment: You have to use AJAX (or push server with socket.io, AJAX is much simpler though). The solution is however quite broad, try implementing it by yourself and post the question once you hit any problems. As per other issue change `<%= @list.each do |m| %>` to `<% @list.each do |m| %>` - there should be no `=`

Comment: @BroiSatse Thank you, I will defiantly look into AJAX. Removing the = fixed the issue with the display. I need to read up more on how to use the erb tags..